# Opencart language prefix causes Nginx 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, opencart, prefix

ENV: nginx + php-fpm

I have installed OC 2.1
When I use SEO URLs around website there is no problems.

example.com/news - [OK, 200] 
example.com/de/news - [OK, 200]

But sometimes I don't have SEO URLs 
example.com/index.php?route=information/testimonials&testimonial_id=6 - [OK, 200]
example.com/en/index.php?route=information/testimonials&testimonial_id=6 - [**ERROR**, **404**]

NGINX:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/example.com;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  charset UTF-8;
  autoindex off;

  # Show "Not Found" 404 errors in place of "Forbidden" 403 errors, because
  # forbidden errors allow attackers potential insight into your server's
  # layout and contents
  error_page 403 =404;

  # It's always good to set logs, note however you cannot turn off the error log
  # Setting error_log off; will simply create a file called 'off'
  access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

  # SEO URL Settings
  # Nginx configuration of OC htaccess

  rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /index.php?route=feed/sitemap last;
  rewrite ^/sitemap([^\.]+).xml$ /index.php?route=feed/sitemap&path=$1 last;

  location = /googlebase.xml {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=feed/google_base; 
  } 

  location / {
    # This try_files directive is used to enable SEO-friendly URLs for OpenCart
    try_files $uri $uri/ @opencart;
  }

  location @opencart {
    rewrite ^([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
  }

  # End SEO settings

  # Make sure files with the following extensions do not get loaded by nginx because nginx would display the source code, and these files can contain PASSWORDS!
  location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|ini|install|log|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
    deny all;
  }

  # Do not log access to the favicon, to keep the logs cleaner
  location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location = /apple-touch-icon.png {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location = /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  # This block will catch static file requests, such as images, css, js
  # The ?: prefix is a 'non-capturing' mark, meaning we do not require
  # the pattern to be captured into $1 which should help improve performance
  location ~* \.(?:3gp|gif|jpg|jpe?g|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso|woff|woff2|eot|otf|ttf)$ {
    # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
    expires max;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
  }

  # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
  # Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
  location ~ /\. {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    deny all;
  }

  location ~ ~$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    deny all;
  }

  # Deny access to any files with a .php extension in these directories
  # Works in sub-directory installs and also in multisite network
  # Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
  location ~* /(?:cache|logs|image|download)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
  }
  
  # Make sure these get through
  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }
  
  # Fix for Firefox issue with cross site font icons
  location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
  }

  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
  }

  # Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    # Regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
    # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    # Uncomment if site is HTTPS
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    include fastcgi.conf;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

} # End of server block.


server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

but in ENV: php + apache2 is everything okay and works well :)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dev.example.com
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap([^\.]+).xml$ index.php?route=feed/sitemap&path=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

php_value max_input_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 10000
```

I guess something with nginx rules and directives, It tries to open /de/ directory and causes 404 error page but apache2 works perfectly and doesn't try to open /de/ directory. 
What Have I missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happened with your nginx config. When some general request (say `/de/news`) arrives at your server, it is processed by `location / { ... }` block where the `try_files` directive checked `/var/www/example.com/de/news` file presence first, then your defined index files presence in the `/var/www/example.com/de/news` directory, and then continues the request processing with the `@opencart` named location, where your request transformed to `/index.php?_route_=/de/news`. After that the `last` flag of the `rewrite` nginx directive forces nginx to search a new location for this transformed request, which is `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) { ... }` one. But when you got a request like `/en/index.php?route=information/testimonials&testimonial_id=6`, it goes directly to that location bypassing the default `location / { ... }` one, the regex matching locations take priority over the prefix locations. After the `fastcgi_split_path_info` directive you have `$fastcgi_script_name` variable equal to `/en/index.php` and the `try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;` obviously gives you an HTTP 404 error.

What you can try to do? For example, you can try `try_files $fastcgi_script_name /index.php?_route_=$uri&$args;`. This directive would transform your `/en/index.php?route=information/testimonials&testimonial_id=6` request to `/index.php?_route_=/en/index.php&route=information/testimonials&testimonial_id=6`. You can rewrite your URI moving this language prefix to some query variable, for example

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    if ($uri ~ ^/(?<lang>en|de|fr)(?<path>/.*)) {
        set $args $args&language=$lang;
        rewrite ^ $path break;
    }
    ...
}
```

You can do whatever you want, there is always a couple of ways to solve a task related to the IT. I hope you understand what is going on in general.

**Afterwords**

Instead of

```
  location / {
    # This try_files directive is used to enable SEO-friendly URLs for OpenCart
    try_files $uri $uri/ @opencart;
  }

  location @opencart {
    rewrite ^([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
  }
```

you can use just

```
  location / {
    # This try_files directive is used to enable SEO-friendly URLs for OpenCart
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_route_=$uri&$args;
  }
```

By `rewrite ^([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1 last;` you probably mean to take the URI part without the query string, but the `rewrite` directive (and the `location` one too) works with the normalized URIs which does not include the query string anyway. If you want to stay with two `location` blocks, this rule can be safely changed to `rewrite ^ /index.php?_route_=$uri last;`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time!
After spending one eternity I understood exactly what you've described!
I also wanted to create additional location rule for php's location, but I've solved it in a different way.
I've changed  try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404; to  try_files $fastcgi_script_name = @opencart;

Comment: @Mafftor Didn't think about it but you're right, it should work too. As I said, there is always a couple of ways to solve some task related to the IT :)